# How to remove the menu in the top panel?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, appmenu

The old menu of Archive, Edit etc. is behind the gnome-shell panel and it's very annoying. How do I remove this menu in the top panel? I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 by the way.

Here is the problem.

[image]

I hope someone can help.

Comment: Cinnamon or gnome-classic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the looks, that's the Ubuntu global menu. To remove it, open a terminal and paste this

```
sudo apt-get remove appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-gtk appmenu-qt
```

You may need to restart your computer afterwards. If you wver want them back, simply reinstall the packages.

Comment: Why he have to remove global menu for just gnome?
It will effect unity also if he is a unity user too.
,

Comment: Thank you very much!! that was the answer :D 
Long days and pleasant nights to you.

Comment: @AboobackerMk I know, it's ridiculous. But i've run into this myself, and it was the only way there seems to be to get around it. If anyone knows of a better way, please let us know!

Comment: But is it gnome-classic  gnome-shell or cinnamon?

Installed gnome-shell extension for global menu?
If yes disable it via gnome-tweak-tool

Comment: No, it wasn't a real menu, it was just like a background, but this worked fine. And it's gnome shell.
I think a part of the classic entered in the shell, but Im not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a better way than removing the appmenu packages. Just type the following:

```
echo '[ ${DESKTOP_SESSION#ubuntu} = $DESKTOP_SESSION ] && unset UBUNTU_MENUPROXY' | sudo tee /etc/X11/Xsession.d/81ubuntu-menu-proxy
```

This will fix the gnome-shell problem but not affect Unity, nor Unity-2D.