# Why this white line appears between top bar and wallpaper?

Tags: 11.10, gnome

After trying on some gnome extensions my desktop looks like this:

[image]

When I maximize something, it fits well to the whole space, but when the desktop is showed, this white line is showed too. It seems like the wallpaper doesn't want to touch the top bar and gives it some space. It happens with all the wallpapers I tried.
Someone could tell me what can I do to fix it? It worked well before trying the extensions.

I've noticed that if I turn off "Have file manager handle the desktop" in Gnome advance settings, the bar disappears but icons on the desktop disappear, too. If I change the Gtk+ theme the bar becomes narrower or changes its colour.

The extensions i've tried were "Music Integration, Overlay Icons, Pidgin Integration, Remove Accesibility and Remove User Name" I've uninstalled them one by one but at the end, the annoying white line remains there, even whit all extensions uninstalled. I've tried also to reset Gnome3 to initial settings doing `rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity` but it seems nothing happened at all.

I tried installing a new gnome shell theme, it didn't work either.

Comment: Can you tell us what extensions? Also, try disabling them one-by-one to try to isolate the issue. If you figure this out, edit your question or post an answer so others can see what was wrong.

Comment: The extensions i've tried were "Music Integration, Overlay Icons, Pidgin Integration, Remove Accesibility and Remove User Name" I've uninstalled them one by one but at the end, the annoying white line remains there, even whit all extensions uninstalled. I've tried also to reset Gnome3 to initial settings doing rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity   but it seems nothing happened at all.

Comment: I would asusme this was a theme problem. Did you install or enable the user theme extension, or install any additional Gnome Shell themes from anywhere?

Comment: Searching "theme" in the Software Center, that's what is installed:gnome-accessibility-themes
community-themes
gnome-themes-extras
gnome-icon-theme-full
gnome-icon-theme-extras
gnome-icon-theme-symbolic
ubuntu-artwork
gnome-themes-more

Comment: As far as I remember, the default theme uses transparency effects at that specific part of the top bar (probably SVG and CSS properties). Does that happen when you use a different Gnome Shell theme? I don't think there is one available from repositories.

Comment: It's not a white bar! It is the Nautilus menú bar! I didn't noticed that due to the activities bar was not transparent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alexandre's comment put me in the way. It's Unity bar.
I solved it just following this steps:

[How to remove the menu in the top panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105233/how-to-remove-the-menu-in-the-top-panel)

Just pasting this on a terminal:

```
    sudo apt-get remove appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-gtk appmenu-qt
```